# Формы скрытие

Tags: jquery

Как на jquery или css сделать,чтобы при нажатии открывалась форма и при нажатии закрывалась.

Answer (score 2):

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements.